# How to load info of a function and save it in scope from resolve in a route using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

How to load info of a function and save it in scope from resolve in a route using AngularJS?

For example:

```
.state('list.employee_list', {
            url: "/employee_list",
            templateUrl: "views/list/employee_list.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Employee list' },
            resolve: {
                "employeesCollection" : function(){
                    alert("LOAD");
                    $scope.myData = myFunction($scope);
                    alert("finished load, now load view");
                }
            }
        })
```

The idea is to load info of a table before loading its view, so the table won't be empty. The function gets the data from Parse.com

EDIT:

config.js

```
.state('list.employee_list', {
            url: "/employee_list",
            templateUrl: "views/list/employee_list.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Employee list' },
            controller: employeeListCtrl,
            resolve: {
                employeesCollection :  employeeListCtrl.loadData(companyID)
            }
        })
```

controllers.js

```
function employeeListCtrl($scope, employeesCollection){
    $scope.employeesCollection = employeesCollection;
}

employeeListCtrl.loadData = function(companyID){
    var employeesCollection = [];
    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    query.equalTo("companyID", companyID);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var estado = results[i].get("sendTest");
            if(estado == "no"){
                results[i].status = "{{ 'FREE' | translate }}";
            }else if(estado == "yes"){
                results[i].status = "{{ 'TEST_SENT' | translate }}";
            }
            console.log(results[i].get("lastName"));
            employeesCollection[i] = results[i];
        }
    }).then(function(redirect) {
        // Everything is done!
        //window.location.href = "#/list/employee_list";
        promise.resolve();
        console.log("LOADED");
        return employeesCollection;
    });
}
```

views/list/employee_list.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in employeesCollection">
                            <td>
                               {{row.get("firstName")}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{row.get("lastName")}}
                            </td>
                                <span class="label label-primary">{{status}}</span>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can accomplish it:

First, create a service to get your data.  Let's say you have a simple service called MyData:

```
app.factory('MyData', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var obj = {};

    obj.get = function (myendpoint) {
        return $http.get('https://some/endpoint/to/get/data/'+myendpoint).then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
        });
    };

    return obj;
}]);
```

Now you can pass that service to the resolve function in your $routeProvider:

```
.when('/events', {
  templateUrl: 'views/events.html',
  controller: 'EventsCtrl',
  resolve: {
    preloaded: function(MyData) {
      return MyData.get('allevents');
    }
  }
})
```

And, in your controller, you can pass the resolve object to gain access to your data:

```
app.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'preloaded', function ($scope, preloaded) {

    $scope.allevents = preloaded;

}]);
```

Comment: I have edited it following your code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't really follow my example, you made your own approach.  In your example, your employeesCollection is simply a function not the collection you want to return.  You need to have a function that returns an object or promise.  Try following my example.  Create a service and pattern your resolve after mine.  You'll have more luck that way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should just load the view, and call your method to get the data from Parse inside your controller.

When you've got the data, just call `$scope.$apply()` to update the bindings, and your table should update. This is probably best practice, and it will allow you to show some sort of loading animation on the table.

Comment: The scope.apply is still not needed because with the new code it doesn't show anything of the view, just a white screen now.